# input/textarea tag crashing from Angular 4+ served by ASP NET 2.1

Tags: angular, input, textarea, angular6, asp.net-core-2.1

Has anyone encountered this before? I checked everywhere on google, and apparently there was no result even from input crashing.

So I have a Angular 6 page served by ASP NET core 2.1, and everything is working as intended so far, until I tried to click on the textarea element on my page, and the entire program just exits. I tried running the APP with the Angular CLI, and no crash occured.

I have tried:

- Clicking into input element (resulted in crash)
- Adding a textarea/input element on a different component (resulted in crash)
- Running the app with Anuglar CLI (no crash occured)

The output given by VS studio 2017 community Edition was:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 5595.8754ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
The program '[11660] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching the IIS Express' Web Browser from Firefox to Microsoft Edge stopped the app from crashing. In fact, with further testing; clicking on the address bar or presumably any text-input on Firefox will crash the IIS Express.

No idea why, and at this stage, I can't spend any more time on this. If anyone finds out why, it would be greatly appreciated if it gets posted here.

P.S. I have not tested this outside of Development mode